# how to write two digit number in text file without overlapping existing number in java using seek method?

Tags: java

```
public void writefunct() {
    try {
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("C:/Users/Yugantar/Desktop/out.txt", "rw");
        try {

            raf.seek(mx);
            raf.writeBytes(Integer.toString(imageid));

            raf.close();

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

suppose the number is 3 then the output in file is right text file output is 333333333333 but if the number is 34 the output is 334334334

how to put file pointer after the number using seek method..?

Comment: Are you struggling with writing the number, or with setting the file pointer? If you're overwriting a part of the file, you should format your number to a fixed-length string first. See `java.text.MessageFormat` and related classes.

Comment: kind of both, actually i m trying to create tilemap engine for myself, i want to store tileid in text file but here is the thing, tilemap is too big so i have to separate each tile by loop method. Total number of tile id is around 234.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time, and put the questions into the body, not into comments.